# First order logic to describe a finite tree

Tags: logic, graph-theory, first-order-logic, model-theory

I am reading the paper [Describing Graphs: a First Order Approach to Graph Canonization](https://people.cs.umass.edu/%7Eimmerman/pub/canon.pdf).

In Corollary 1.8.2, the paper says

> Let $TREES$ be the set of finite trees. Then $vc(TREES)=2$.

where $vc(TREES)=\max_n vc(TREES, n)$ and define $vc(TREES, n)$ to be the minimum $k$ such that $\mathcal{C}_k$ ($k$-variable first order logic with counting) characterizes the graphs in $TREES$ with at most $n$ vertices.

Assume there is a path (belong to the set $TREES$) of length $r$ starting from $x$ and ending with $y$. Does this corollary mean such a path of length $r$ can be written in $\mathcal{C}_2$? However, I don't think a path of length $r>1$ can be written in $\mathcal{C}_2$ and Proposition 1.5.2 in this paper says such a path can be written in $\mathcal{L}_3$. I am really confused by this inconsistency.

Comment: I'm not sure if the $P_r(x_1, x_2)$ from Proposition 1.5.2 can be written in $\mathcal C_2$, but this is different from $\mathcal C_2$ characterizing the graph which *is* a path of length $r$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an illustration, here is how we can characterize the graph $P_n$ in $\mathcal C_2$.

First, we can express the degree sequence of a graph. The statement $$D(i,j) \equiv (\exists!i\, x_1)((\exists!j\, x_2) E(x_1, x_2))$$ says that there are exactly $i$ vertices of degree $j$. We don't fully characterize $P_n$ by saying that it has $n$ vertices: $2$ vertices of degree $1$ and $n-2$ vertices of degree $2$. However, it will help for the next step.

Second, we can recursively define the statement $L_k(x_i)$ meaning that the closest leaf to $x_i$ is at distance $k$. We have:

- $L_0(x_1) \equiv (\exists!\, x_2)(E(x_1, x_2))$ (this just says $x_1$ is a leaf).
- Recursively, $L_k(x_1) \equiv \neg L_{k-1}(x_1) \land (\exists x_2)(E(x_1, x_2) \land L_{k-1}(x_2))$.

The exact characterization of $P_n$ depends on whether $n$ is even or odd. $P_{2k}$ is characterized by giving its degree sequence, together with $$(\exists!2\,x_1)(\exists!\,x_2)(L_{k-1}(x_1) \land L_{k-1}(x_2) \land E(x_1, x_2))$$
That is, there are two adjacent vertices at distance $k-1$ from a leaf. For $P_{2k+1}$, we could instead say
$$
   (\exists!\,x_1)(\exists!2\,x_2)(L_{k-1}(x_2) \land E(x_1, x_2))
$$
That is, there is a vertex with two neighbors at distance $k-1$ from a leaf.

(In both cases, knowing the vertex degrees tells us that the two paths to a leaf we find can't possibly merge, which gives us a path of length $n-1$ total. Then, knowing the total number of edges from the vertex degrees, we know that there are no other edges we haven't identified.)

---

What we do for trees in general is a bit harder to do explicitly, which is why Theorem 1.8.1 is proven using pebble games instead. But the idea above is very closely related to the idea of "vertex refinement" used in that proof. We start by identifying the vertices of $P_n$ just by their degrees: there's two vertices of degree $1$ and $n-2$ vertices of degree $2$. Then, we can distinguish the $n-2$ vertices of degree $2$ further: two of them have neighbors of degree $1$, and the rest don't. Among the $n-4$ unclassified vertices, two have neighbors which have neighbors of degree $1$, and so on. Eventually, we can distinguish all the vertices, up to the automorphism of $P_n$ which swaps the two ends.

Comment: Thanks. I still have some questions here. (1) Two adjacent vertices at distance $k-1$ from a leaf seems to be the characterization of $P_{2k-1}$ and a vertex with two neighbors at distance $k-1$ from a leaf seems to be the characterization of $P_{2k}$. (2) The characterization of $P_n$ here relies on the leaf node. Can a path in a tree still be characterized by $\mathcal{C}_2$?

Comment: Can you be specific about what you mean by "characterizing a path in a tree"?

Comment: I mean if $P_r(x_1, x_2)$ is a path in a tree, can it be written in $\mathcal{C}_2$?

Comment: No, because $x_1$ and $x_2$ are already both your variables: you can't introduce a third, so you can't say anything meaningful about the relationship between $x_1$ and $x_2$. (Unless $r=1$, in which case $E(x_1, x_2)$ will work.)

Comment: Oh, and I missed your other question. Consider for example $P_4$: `v1 --- v2 --- v3 --- v4`. This has two adjacent vertices at distance $1$ from a leaf. $P_5$, on the other hand is `v1 --- v2 --- v3 --- v4 --- v5`. This has one vertex with two neighbors at distance $2$ from a leaf. So everything is fine. (You might be thinking that $P_n$ should be the path of length $n$, but it's not: $P_n$ is the $n$-vertex path.)